# Customization tools for juno

Tags: display, settings, release-juno

Anybody knows if there are any plans or third party initiative to allow some level of customization to Juno?

In particular I have a small display so I always try to maximize the usable screen. In gnome I use extensions such as [pixel saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) and [hide top bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/)

I know that eos developers are reluctant to let user mess with the default user experience, but I was wondering if, nevertheless, such a customization will be possible with Juno?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

It will add an extra icon in settings.